# TensorFlow export compute graph to XML, JSON, etc

Tags: json, xml, tensorflow, export

I want to export a TensorFlow compute graph to XML or something similar so I can modify it with an external program and then re-import it. I found [Meta Graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/meta_graph/) but this exports in a binary format which I wouldn't know how to modify.

Does such capability exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The native serialization format for TensorFlow's dataflow graph uses [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), which have bindings in many different languages. You can generate code that should be able to parse the binary data from the two message schemas: [`tensorflow.GraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f94e20f2c704f037a113d350fd7c431e3fd75df8/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.proto) (a lower-level representation) and [`tensorflow.MetaGraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f94e20f2c704f037a113d350fd7c431e3fd75df8/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto) (a higher-level representation, which includes a `GraphDef` and other information about how to interpret some of the nodes in the graph).

If there is no protocol buffer implementation for your target language, you can generate JSON from the Python protocol buffer object. For example, the following generates a string containing a JSON representation of a `GraphDef`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import json_format

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
  # Add nodes to the graph...

graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

json_string = json_format.MessageToJson(graph_def)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me unless I did "with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:"

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I've updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Can you go backwards? JSON to Protobuf?

Comment: You can do the reverse with: `graph_def = tf.GraphDef(); json_format.Parse(json_string, graph_def)`

Comment: I am having problems with variables. Does this not work for variables as well? do I need to do something like https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variables/. I was hoping to only have a single file

Comment: Some of the variable structure is lost when you convert to a `tf.GraphDef`. If you want to be able to reconstruct all of the `tf.Variable` objects, you should serialize to/deserialize from a `tf.MetaGraphDef` instead. See [these docs on MetaGraphs] for more details.