# TensorFlow Shape and Type Inference

Tags: json, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I learned that I can program TensorFlow by modifying JSON that come from protobuf. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575442/tensorflow-export-compute-graph-to-xml-json-etc/41576075)

If I modify this JSON, then I sometimes have a problem where I need to manually edit the JSON to propagate the proper shapes of the various inputs and outputs. Is there a way to make TF do this automatically for me so that I can specify inputs via Placeholders and then the shapes and types are automatically propagated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which types of modifications you're going to be making, you could just remove that shape information from the placeholders. The uncertainty will propagate automatically. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])
derived = (placeholder / 3)[1:, None]
print(placeholder.get_shape(), derived.get_shape())
```

Prints:

```
(TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(1)]))
```

So there will be no static shape information saved for the length of `placeholder`. You can even have Tensors with unknown rank.

Re-computing static shapes is a tempting thought, but this is not currently supported because graph construction can depend on static shape information. For example:

```
placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2])
if placeholder.get_shape()[0].value % 2 == 0:
    derived = placeholder
else:
    derived = tf.concat(0, [placeholder, [0]])
```

This isn't a recommended graph construction technique (much better to use `tf.shape` with `cond`), but it does happen. This kind of static-shape-conditional graph structure is not captured in the meta-graph, unfortunately.

Comment: Is the shape propagated once I call `sess.run(out, feed_dict={...})` based on the inputs? If so, then this is perfect for me. Can type be propagated the same way? The problem is that I can't be sure what shape or type my field will be before hand without writing a lot of code.

Comment: Yes, the "true" shape of a Tensor is known at graph execution time (`sess.run`), and can be computed with as part of the graph with `tf.shape` (which returns an integer Tensor). Unfortunately I know of nothing similar for dtype.