# Serializing and deserializing Tensorflow model in memory and continue training

Tags: python, serialization, tensorflow, keras

I have seen variations of this question asked, but I haven't quite found a satisfactory answer yet. Basically, I would like to do the equivalent from keras `model.to_json()`, `model.get_weights()`, `model.from_json()`, `model.set_weights()` to tensorflow. I think I am getting close to there, but I am at a point where I am stuck. I'd prefer if I could get the weights and graph in the same string, but I understand if that isn't possible.

Currently, what I have is:

```
g = optimizer.minimize(loss_op,
                       global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
de = g.graph.as_graph_def()
json_string = json_format.MessageToJson(de)

gd = tf.GraphDef()
gd = json_format.Parse(json_string, gd)
```

That seems to create the graph fine, but obviously the meta graph is not included for variable, weights, etc. There is also the meta graph, but the only thing I see is export_meta_graph, which doesn't seem to serialize in the same manner. I saw that MetaGraph has a proto function, but I don't know how to serialize those variables.

So in short, how would you take a tensorflow model (model as in weights, graph, etc), serialize it to a string (preferably json), then deserialize it and continue training or serve predictions.

Here are things that get me close to there and I have tried, but mostly has limitations in needing to write to disk, which I can't do in this case:

[Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/tokestermw/795cc1fd6d0c9069b20204cbd133e36b)

[This is the closest one I found, but the link to serializing a metagraph doesn't exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575442/tensorflow-export-compute-graph-to-xml-json-etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the equivalent of [keras](https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/) `Model.get_weights()` and `Model.set_weights()`, these methods aren't strongly tied to keras internals and can be easily extracted.

### Original code

Here's how they look like in keras source code:

```py
def get_weights(self):
  weights = []
  for layer in self.layers:
    weights += layer.weights
  return K.batch_get_value(weights)   # this is just `get_session().run(weights)`

def set_weights(self, weights):
  tuples = []
  for layer in self.layers:
    num_param = len(layer.weights)
    layer_weights = weights[:num_param]
    for sw, w in zip(layer.weights, layer_weights):
      tuples.append((sw, w))
    weights = weights[num_param:]
  K.batch_set_value(tuples)  # another wrapper over `get_session().run(...)`
```

Keras's `weights` is the list of numpy arrays (not json). As you can see, it uses the fact that model architecture is known (`self.layers`) which allows it to reconstruct the correct mapping from variables to values. Some seemingly non-trivial work is done in [`K.batch_set_value`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2236), but in fact it simply prepares assign ops and runs them in session.

### Getting and setting weights in pure tensorflow

```py
def tensorflow_get_weights():
  vars = tf.trainable_variables()
  values = tf.get_default_session().run(vars)
  return zip([var.name for var in vars], values)

def tensorflow_set_weights(weights):
  assign_ops = []
  feed_dict = {}
  for var_name, value in weights:
    var = tf.get_default_session().graph.get_tensor_by_name(var_name)
    value = np.asarray(value)
    assign_placeholder = tf.placeholder(var.dtype, shape=value.shape)
    assign_op = tf.assign(var, assign_placeholder)
    assign_ops.append(assign_op)
    feed_dict[assign_placeholder] = value
  tf.get_default_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Here I assume that you want to serialize / deserialize the *whole* model (i.e., all trainable variables) and in the *default* session. If this is not the case, functions above are easily customizable.

### Testing

```py
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 5], dtype=tf.float32, name='x')
W = tf.Variable(np.zeros([5, 5]), dtype=tf.float32, name='W')
b = tf.Variable(np.zeros([5]), dtype=tf.float32, name='b')
y = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W), b)

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  # Save the weights
  w = tensorflow_get_weights()
  print(W.eval(), b.eval())

  # Update the model
  session.run([tf.assign(W, np.ones([5, 5])), tf.assign(b, np.ones([5]) * 2)])
  print(W.eval(), b.eval())

  # Restore the weights
  tensorflow_set_weights(w)
  print(W.eval(), b.eval())
```

If you run this test, you should see the model was freezed at zeros, then got updated and then restored back to zeros.

Comment: Awesome. I'll take a look this morning.

Comment: @Derek_M absolutely. Just let me know if you have further questions

Comment: I think you got me there, and I will accept this answer here in a bit. I created two gists. One is using the method above https://gist.github.com/dmmiller612/75e0f515083d3c61f0024a0e22662804 . The other one uses all json, even the weights. https://gist.github.com/dmmiller612/97025b27eeb3250fe190e92f758cdc9a Do these look right on first glance?

Comment: I don't think `json.dumps(weights)` will do what you want (at least with this version). See the caveat. If you really want to be able to serialize it to json, I'll update my answer so that `weights` contains only primitive types

Comment: Oh okay. I actually took out the variables, and converted the numpy weights to a list, then reconverted them back to numpy arrays. It seemed to at least not fail. Would this still be the case?

Comment: Yes, this way it should work. Note that `tensorflow_set_weights` converts all values to numpy array

Comment: Awesome, I will post a a response with everything. Thanks for getting me there!

Answer (score 4):

Note that the solution from @Maxim will create new operations in the graph each time it runs.

If you run the function very frequently this will cause your code to get slower and slower.

Two solutions to work around this problem:

1. Create the assign operations at the same time as the rest of the graph and reuse them:

   ```
   assign_ops = []
   for var_name in tf.trainable_variables():
       assign_placeholder = tf.placeholder(var.dtype, shape=value.shape)
       assign_op = var.assign(assign_placeholder)
       assign_ops.append(assign_op)
   ```
2. Use the load function on the variables, I prefer this one as it removes the need for the code above:

   ```
   self.params = tf.trainable_variables()

   def get_weights(self):
       values = tf.get_default_session().run(self.params)
       return values

   def set_weights(self, weights):
       for i, value in enumerate(weights):
           value = np.asarray(value)
           self.params[i].load(value, self.sess)
   ```

(I can't comment so I put this as an answer instead)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [freeze_graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)

This script is included in Tensorflow and allows you to take a GraphDef proto, a SaverDef proto, and a set of variable values stored in a checkpoint file.

In this way you can output a GraphDef with all of the variable ops converted into const ops containing the values of the variables.

To restore a frozen model you have to reinitialize graphs and remap inputs from the frozen model, see [this example](https://gist.github.com/tokestermw/795cc1fd6d0c9069b20204cbd133e36b)

Comment: Right, that is the gist that I linked. It still seems to need to go to disk, right? It also seems like that gist doesn't use tensorflow's freeze graph function (it is commented out), and I was curious if there was a reason why.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Maxim for getting me to the solution. I wanted to post an answer with both the graph and weights being converted to json for people that stumble across this problem. To just serialize the graph and not the weights, I created a gist that encapsulates what Maxim wrote here: [Tensorflow graph with non json serialized weights](https://gist.github.com/dmmiller612/75e0f515083d3c61f0024a0e22662804)

Now to serialize/deserialize both the graph and weights, I created a separate gist here: [Tensorflow graph with json serialized weights and graph](https://gist.github.com/dmmiller612/97025b27eeb3250fe190e92f758cdc9a).

To run through the explanation, I first slightly tweaked the weight functions by not returning the variables in get weights, and in set weights, grabbing the current variables there. The is an important caveat, especially if the graph is slightly different than the current trainable variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from google.protobuf import json_format
import json

def tensorflow_get_weights():
    vs = tf.trainable_variables()
    values = tf.get_default_session().run(vs)
    return values

def tensorflow_set_weights(weights):
    assign_ops = []
    feed_dict = {}
    vs = tf.trainable_variables()
    zipped_values = zip(vs, weights)
    for var, value in zipped_values:
        value = np.asarray(value)
        assign_placeholder = tf.placeholder(var.dtype, shape=value.shape)
        assign_op = var.assign(assign_placeholder)
        assign_ops.append(assign_op)
        feed_dict[assign_placeholder] = value
    tf.get_default_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Next, I created two utility functions that would convert weights to and from json:

```
def convert_weights_to_json(weights):
    weights = [w.tolist() for w in weights]
    weights_list = json.dumps(weights)
    return weights_list

def convert_json_to_weights(json_weights):
    loaded_weights = json.loads(json_weights)
    loaded_weights = [np.asarray(x) for x in loaded_weights]
    return loaded_weights
```

Than I had a method that initially ran to kick off training. This method would initialize variables, run the optimization, get the weights and graph, and convert them into json. It looks like:

```
def run_initial_with_json_weights(opti, feed_dict):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(0, 250):
            sess.run(opti, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        first_weights = tensorflow_get_weights()
        g = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
    json_string = json_format.MessageToJson(g)
    return json_string, convert_weights_to_json(first_weights)
```

Now that we have the serialized weights and graph, if we want to continue training and or make predictions, we can do the following. This method deserializes the graphdef and weights, runs the optimization, then makes predictions.

```
def run_serialized(json_graph, json_weights, feed_dict):
    gd = tf.GraphDef()
    gd = json_format.Parse(json_graph, gd)
    weights = convert_json_to_weights(json_weights)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.import_graph_def(gd)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        nu_out = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('outer/Sigmoid:0')
        mini = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('mini:0')
        tensorflow_set_weights(weights)

        for i in range(0, 50):
             sess.run(mini, feed_dict=feed_dict)

        predicted = sess.run(nu_out, feed_dict=feed_dict)

    return predicted
```

A full xor example is in the gist above.